# Merging data into an existing pandas dataframe column conditionally

Tags: python, pandas, merge, data-manipulation

I have the following data:

```py
one_dict = {0: "zero", 1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three", 4: "four"}
two_dict = {0: "light", 1: "calc", 2: "line", 3: "blur", 4: "color"}
np.random.seed(2)
n = 15
a_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=np.random.randint(0, 4, n), b=np.random.randint(0, 3, n)))
a_df["c"] = np.nan
a_df = a_df.sort_values("b").reset_index(drop=True)
```

where the dataframe looks as:

```
In [45]: a_df
Out[45]:
    a  b   c
0   3  0 NaN
1   1  0 NaN
2   0  0 NaN
3   2  0 NaN
4   3  0 NaN
5   1  0 NaN
6   2  1 NaN
7   2  1 NaN
8   3  1 NaN
9   0  2 NaN
10  3  2 NaN
11  3  2 NaN
12  0  2 NaN
13  3  2 NaN
14  1  2 NaN
```

I would like to replace values in `c` with those from dictionaries `one_dict`
and `two_dict`, with the result as follows:

```
In [45]: a_df
Out[45]:
    a  b   c
0   3  0 three
1   1  0 one
2   0  0 zero
3   2  0 .
4   3  0 .
5   1  0 .
6   2  1 calc
7   2  1 calc
8   3  1 blur
9   0  2 NaN
10  3  2 NaN
11  3  2 NaN
12  0  2 NaN
13  3  2 NaN
14  1  2 NaN
```

## Attempt

I'm not sure what a good approach to this would be though.

I thought that I might do something along the following lines:

```py
merge_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(one = one_dict, two=two_dict)).reset_index()
merge_df['zeros'] = 0
merge_df['ones'] = 1
```

giving

```py
In [62]: merge_df
Out[62]:
   index    one    two  zeros  ones
0      0   zero  light      0     1
1      1    one   calc      0     1
2      2    two   line      0     1
3      3  three   blur      0     1
4      4   four  color      0     1
```

Then merge this into the `a_df`, but I'm not sure how to merge in and update
at the same time, or if this is a good approach.

## Edit

- keys correspond to the values of column `a`
- `.` is just shorthand, this should be filled in with the value as others are

Comment: what do the keys in your dict correspond to?

Comment: What is the update logic here?

Comment: the `.` are just short hand, they would be filled

Comment: @QuangHoang not sure which part you're referring to

Comment: edited the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just matter of creating new dataframe with the correct structure and merge:

```
(a_df.drop('c', axis=1)
    .merge(pd.DataFrame([one_dict,two_dict])
               .rename_axis(index='b',columns='a')
               .stack().reset_index(name='c'),
           on=['a','b'],
           how='left')
)
```

Output:

```
    a  b      c
0   3  0  three
1   1  0    one
2   0  0   zero
3   2  0    two
4   3  0  three
5   1  0    one
6   2  1   line
7   2  1   line
8   3  1   blur
9   0  2    NaN
10  3  2    NaN
11  3  2    NaN
12  0  2    NaN
13  3  2    NaN
14  1  2    NaN
```

Comment: I didn't imagine to rename the lookup frame to help with the merging.  That's a neat trick, will be saving this in the bag, thanks! +1